# How to Rename all the all the names in a column duplicates in Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I had a problem while renaming all the duplicate names in the data frame Column.

```
Column 1: x,y,z,....(all different names)
Column 2: a,b,c,.....(all different names)
Column 3: p,pq,r,s,p,s,r,pq,p.....
```

I need Column 3 as p_1,pq_1,r_1,s_1,p_2,s_2,r_2,pq_2,p_3,.....

I had lot of duplicates in column 3 but i want to name all as said above.

I tried below code and got output as:

```
Column 3: p,pq,r,s,p_1,s_1,r_1,pq_1,p_2,.....

def df_name_uniquify(RS):
    df_names = RS["Column 3"]
    new_names = []
    for item in df_names:
        counter = 0
        newitem = item
        while newitem in new_names:
            counter += 1
            newitem = "{}_{}".format(item, counter)
        new_names.append(newitem)
    RS["Column 3"] = new_names
    return RS
df = df_name_uniquify(RS)
```

Any suggestions or modification of code will be helpful

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`cumcount()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) here:

```
df['new_col']=df.Column3+'_'+(df.groupby('Column3').cumcount()+1).astype(str)
print(df)
```

---

```
  Column3 new_col
0       p     p_1
1      pq    pq_1
2       r     r_1
3       s     s_1
4       p     p_2
5       s     s_2
6       r     r_2
7      pq    pq_2
8       p     p_3
```